# Multi Line Customizable List

Tags: angularjs

I need to create a "column chooser". Basically two lists left/right with the ability to move items from one to another using buttons.

Usually simple `select>option` with `size=10` would be enough. But (as always) I need to be able to customize list items. Is there any ready solution for customizable lists?

I did found custom versions for dropdown lists, but not list-lists (ie `ui-select`).

Comment: If you can't find it, why don't you do it yourself? It looks quite straightforward: one left list (the source), two buttons (`select`, `deselect`), and one right list (the destination). On `select` click, you add the current item from first list to the second, and remove it from the first. The opposite on `deselect` click... :-)

Comment: hi, it's not the issue of of two lists, is customizable list items what is hard, as HTML don't support styling of `option`s.

Comment: I see... Once I did try to someway customize an html select/option, but soon I did give up, due to huge compatibility problems it produces... :-( However, it's not clear to me (sorry) why and how you want to customize a `list`, and what do you mean by "list-lists"?...

Comment: This is a requirement I have. I have a huge list (~3000) items, and some of them can be chosen to be seen in a grid (simple usually). But then there're special columns, that needs "special" design